# WPF Toolkit:AutoCompleteBox does not move accordingly as the main Window

Tags: c#, wpf, autocompletebox

I am developing a WPF application for my client and I need to use the toolkit:AutoCompleteBox I have implemented it as accordingly as I could but now I am facing an issue. Whenever I try type something in the AutoCompleteBox say "a" see in the picture attached it pops up the list, but at this moment if I try to move the window to left or right or top the list remain exactly in the same location where it pops up. it is not moving with the window. Any idea why is it like that?

how can I go for a smooth solution like move accordingly as the mainWindow. Please help.!

[image: Bug for AutoCompleteBox]

Comment: If it's an option, I'd suggest closing the dropdown when moving the window, I think it'd save some headaches. Moving it properly so it stays with the window is not exactly trivial to do properly, which is why I'm guessing the WPF toolkit authors chose not to worry about it.

Comment: @AlexPaven I would say that's actually a good way of implementation, but how do I achieve that, how do I know when the MainWindow is resizing or moving left / right, and then I have to close the AutoCompleteBox at that time.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Popups are own Windows and do not belong to your MainWindow. The author of the AutoCompleteBox decided not to implement a default behavior for location changes.

For example, you can register for `Application.Current.MainWindow.SizeChanged` or `LocationChanged`. Than set `IsDropDownOpen` to false. But be carefull, this can cause memory leaks if you do not unregister properly (e.g. when you change your screen to sth. else).

You could also register for `IsKeyBoardFocusWithinChanged` of the control to close the DropDown if IsKeyboardFocusWithin is false.